# Getting a WooCommerce Product Properties from WP_Query Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that uses WP_Query to loop through product post types.  Within this function I can get things from the post object like permalink, the title, the image etc for the product post.  However for each product in the loop and I need to access the product object because I want to calculate and display the review ratings.  I was using global $product and then $product->get_rating_count() etc to get the data needed.  However while debugging another bit of code I found the well known 'ID was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly.' error for this function.

Everything still works (with debugging turned off), but I want to be sure that it still works in future versions of WooCommerce.  Does anybody know I can from within a WP_Query loop (that is looping through the product post types) access the product object properties without this error?

Here is my code....

```
<?php
// Get the product rating
global $product;
if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) ) {
return;
}
$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();
if ( $rating_count > 0 ) : ?>
<div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
  <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $average, $rating_count ); ?>
  <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $product->ID ); ?>#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(
    <?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)
  </a>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `$product` variable is an instance of the `WC_Product` class which is different from the `WP_Post` class. You can read about the `WC_Product` API here:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

The correct way to get the product ID in this case is using the `get_id` method:

`$product->get_id()`

Comment: So instead of 'global $product' just use $product->get_id()?

Comment: @ChrisHawkins I guess you would still need the `global $product` to make the `$product` variable available to use, but in case you don't want to use that, you can also use `$product = wc_get_product($product_id)`. It will give you the same result.

Comment: Yeah I have tried to use wc_get_product() as well but the results were the same.  WooCommerce is complaining that I am accessing the product directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I needed some sleep....

After looking at this again this morning I can see something that for some reason I was glazing over before.  I was calling $product->ID for the link of the product but of course it should now be $product->get_id().  With that change it is now working.